# Regular expression to match everything, except HTML tags

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

```
<tr><td>Di, 12.04.16</td><td>1</td><td>D</td><td>D</td><td>255</td><td>ABC</td><tr>
```

I want to only match ABC or anything else that stand between

```
<td>
</td> (before and after ABC)
```

This Patter doesnt work for me:

```
((?!<tr><td>[D-M][i-r],[' ][0-3][0-9]\\.[0-1][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]</td><td>[1-9][0-2]?</td><td>[A-Z]?[A-Z]?[A-Z]?[A-Z]?[1-5]?</td><td>(---|[A-Z]?[A-Z]?[A-Z]?[A-Z]?[1-5]?)</td><td>).*(?!</td></tr>))
```

Do you have any idea?
Thx for help

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse HTML.  HTML is not a regular language.  Use something like HTMLAgilityPack instead.

Comment: obligatory HTML parsing link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Jeremy: It almost feels like the OP was inspired by that question, judging from the title that was chosen.

Comment: Yes, thx for anwering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amy said, don't use regex to parse HTML. You can install [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) from NuGet and use [System.Linq Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.linq%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to parse it.

For example here:

```
string html = "<html><head></head><body><p class='testclass'>This is a paragraph.</p><table><tr><td>Di, 12.04.16</td><td>1</td><td>D</td><td>D</td><td>255</td><td>ABC</td><tr></table></body></html>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var programmes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => d.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "testclass");
var trs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr"); // Give you all the trs
foreach (var tr in trs)
{
    var tds = tr.Descendants("td").ToArray(); // Get all the tds
    //Sample, show the result in a TextBlock
    foreach (var td in tds)
    {
        txt.Text = txt.Text + " " + td.InnerText;
    }
}
```

The result is so:

[image]