# Binding text with <P> to textblock UWP

Tags: c#, text, binding, uwp

I have a text with paragraph element. How can I bind it to text block, without attribute? 
I use MVVM so don't need code-behind solution.

Text example:

```
<p xmlns:l=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\">В истории мирового кинематографа с именем Альфреда Хичкока – режиссера, продюсера, сценариста – неразрывно связан жанр триллера и понятие саспенса. Закомплексованный толстяк обладал волшебным даром, позволявшим ему обращать вечно терзавшие его страхи на пользу творчеству: Хичкок мастерски создавал в своих фильмах атмосферу тревожной неопределенности и напряженного ожидания. Странный, склонный к жестоким розыгрышам человек, в молодости испытавший влияние немецкого и русского кино, не боялся экспериментировать и постоянно использовал новаторские, а порой и шокирующие приемы. Ровесник кинематографа, он рос вместе с ним, создавая и развивая новые жанры, от комедийного триллера до фильма ужасов и тончайшего психологического детектива. Ему довелось работать с самыми звездными актерами Голливуда, такими как Ингрид Бергман, Кэри Грант, Джеймс Стюарт, Грейс Келли. Фильмы Хичкока стали классикой мирового кинематографа, он удостоен звезды на голливудской Аллее славы, почетной награды Американского института кино, ордена Британской империи.</p>
```

Comment: what the problem? you want to remove `<p xmlns:l...>` and `</p>`?

Comment: I want to implement it, but not to show <p xmlns:l...> in TextBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to extract part in the string `<p xmlns:l=...>...</p>` in ViewModel, just for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind VM.Paragraph}" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public string Paragraph { get; set; }
...
var pra = "<p xmlns:l=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\">В истории мирового кинематографа с именем Альфреда Хичкока – режиссера, продюсера, сценариста – неразрывно связан жанр триллера и понятие саспенса. Закомплексованный толстяк обладал волшебным даром, позволявшим ему обращать вечно терзавшие его страхи на пользу творчеству: Хичкок мастерски создавал в своих фильмах атмосферу тревожной неопределенности и напряженного ожидания. Странный, склонный к жестоким розыгрышам человек, в молодости испытавший влияние немецкого и русского кино, не боялся экспериментировать и постоянно использовал новаторские, а порой и шокирующие приемы. Ровесник кинематографа, он рос вместе с ним, создавая и развивая новые жанры, от комедийного триллера до фильма ужасов и тончайшего психологического детектива. Ему довелось работать с самыми звездными актерами Голливуда, такими как Ингрид Бергман, Кэри Грант, Джеймс Стюарт, Грейс Келли. Фильмы Хичкока стали классикой мирового кинематографа, он удостоен звезды на голливудской Аллее славы, почетной награды Американского института кино, ордена Британской империи.</p>";
var match = Regex.Match(pra, "<p xmlns:l=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\">(.*)</p>");
Paragraph = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

But if you're trying to parse HTML, don't use regular expression, it's better to use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), you can refer to this thread: [Regular expression to match everything, except HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553222/regular-expression-to-match-everything-except-html-tags/36568133#36568133).